# TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code taken from the metaplex repo: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';

import '../styles/index.less';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Metaplex NFT Marketplace</title>
      </Head>
      <div id="root">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

But I get the following error when doing yarn start which runs the following command

```
cross-env CI=true lerna run start --scope @oyster/common --stream --parallel --scope web
```

in the metaplex repo and going to localhost:3000:

```
Server Error
TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/pages/_app.tsx (10:8) @ App

   8 | <>
   9 |   <Head>
> 10 |     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
     |    ^
  11 |     <title>Metaplex NFT Marketplace</title>
  12 |   </Head>
  13 |   <div id="root">
Call Stack
d
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js (33:498)
bb
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js (36:16)
a.b.render
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js (42:43)
a.b.read
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js (41:83)
exports.renderToString
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js (52:138)
Object.renderPage
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js (53:854)
Function.getInitialProps
../../node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js (9:158)
Function.getInitialProps
src/pages/_document.tsx (11:31)
loadGetInitialProps
file:///Users/prikshetsharma/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js (5:101)
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to run yarn install?

Comment: no I didn't forget to yarn install

Comment: did you found the solution, how did you fixed this problem?@zendevil.eth